# Palm Treo 700p : not an MTP device

Tags: usb, 13.10, mtp, jpilot

Palm Treo 700p : not an MTP device (syslog error) : Jpilot HotSync Timeout

The phone is ancient by today's standards, but it does what I need and I like it. 
Two or three ubuntu os upgrades ago JPilot stopped being able to sync with my phone. 
I had limited internet access, and my search turned up articles saying it was discontinued due to it being outdated, and minimal usage.

I now have some time to research and I've found lots of documents about how to get it working on older version, and all the different work arounds that have occurred over the years and I've made it to this point. I need some help.

Using all the help docs, and discussion threads, I pieced together these steps, and tossed them in a script (easier to tests the results).

```
~$ cat palm_treo_usb.sh 
echo "************** Starting *****************\n";

echo "************** modprobe usbserial *****************\n";
/sbin/modprobe usbserial;

echo "************** modprobe visor *****************\n";
/sbin/modprobe visor

echo "************** lsmod  *****************\n";
/sbin/lsmod | grep "[v|u][i|s][s|b]";

echo "************** Groups  *****************\n";
cat /etc/group | grep dial;
cat /etc/group | grep tty;

echo "************** modprobe *****************\n";
modprobe visor product=0x61 vendor=0x830;
tail -n20 /var/log/kern.log |grep -A25 "device disconnected"| grep "[u|U|j|v|p][s|S|i|p][b|B|s|i|l]" | grep -v Logitech | grep "Aug 29";

rm /dev/ttyUSB0;
rm /dev/ttyUSB1;
#rm /dev/ttyUSB2;
rm /dev/ttyUSB3;
ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*;

echo "************** proc devices *****************\n";
cat /proc/devices | grep "[u|U][s|S][b|B]";

echo "************** mknob 0 *****************\n";
/bin/mknod /dev/ttyUSB0 c 188 0;
echo "************** mknob 1 *****************\n";
/bin/mknod /dev/ttyUSB1 c 188 1;
#echo "************** mknob 2 *****************\n";
#/bin/mknod /dev/ttyUSB2 c 188 2;
echo "************** mknob 3 *****************\n";
/bin/mknod /dev/ttyUSB3 c 188 3;

echo "************** chmod and chown  *****************\n";
chmod 0666 /dev/ttyUSB*;
chown root:dialout /dev/ttyUSB*;
echo "************** /dev/ttyUSB*  *****************\n";
ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*;

echo "************** pilot.rules *****************\n";
#ls -al /etc/udev/rules.d/pilot.rules;
#echo 'BUS=="usb", SYSFS{product}=="Palm Handheld*|Handspring *", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", NAME="ttyUSB%n", SYMLINK="pilot", GROUP="esouthworth", MODE="0666"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/pilot.rules;
ls -al /etc/udev/rules.d/palmtreo.rules;
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/palmtreo.rules;

echo "************** pilot-dlpsh 0 *****************\n";
pilot-dlpsh -c --port=/dev/ttyUSB0 &
echo "************** pilot-dlpsh 1 *****************\n";
pilot-dlpsh -c --port=/dev/ttyUSB1 &
echo "************** pilot-dlpsh 2 *****************\n";
pilot-dlpsh -c --port=/dev/ttyUSB2 &
echo "************** pilot-dlpsh 3 *****************\n";
pilot-dlpsh -c --port=/dev/ttyUSB3 &


echo "************** pilot-xfer 0 *****************\n";
pilot-xfer -l --port=/dev/ttyUSB0 &
echo "************** pilot-xfer 1  *****************\n";
pilot-xfer -l --port=/dev/ttyUSB1 &
echo "************** pilot-xfer 2  *****************\n";
pilot-xfer -l --port=/dev/ttyUSB2 &
echo "************** pilot-xfer 3  *****************\n";
pilot-xfer -l --port=/dev/ttyUSB3 &

echo "************** /dev/ttyUSB*  *****************\n";
ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*;
echo "************** /dev/bus/usb/*  *****************\n";
ls -al /dev/bus/usb/*;
echo "************** /sys/dev/char/18*  *****************\n";
ls -al /sys/dev/char/18*;
echo "************** /dev/usb/*  *****************\n";
ls -al /dev/usb*;

tail -n20 /var/log/kern.log |grep -A25 "device disconnected"| grep "[u|U|j|v|p][s|S|i|p][b|B|s|i|l]" | grep -v Logitech | grep "Aug 29";

ps -aux | grep "[u|U|j|v|p][s|S|i|p][b|B|s|i|l]" | grep -v upstart;

echo "************** lsusb  *****************\n";
lsusb | grep Palm;

echo "************** sylog  *****************\n";
tail -n20 /var/log/syslog | grep -A25 "new full-speed USB device";

echo "************** ftdi_sio  *****************\n";
modinfo ftdi_sio | head -n6;
modinfo ftdi_sio | tail -n6;

ps -aux | grep "pilot";
ps -aux | grep "usb";
ps -aux | grep "mode";
```

This is my output results:

```
    root@Toshiba-Satellite-P105:/home/esouthworth# ./palm_treo_usb.sh 
************** Starting *****************\n
************** modprobe usbserial *****************\n
************** modprobe visor *****************\n
************** lsmod  *****************\n
visor                  13355  0 
usbserial              38603  1 visor
usbhid                 47361  0 
hid                    87370  3 hid_generic,usbhid
************** Groups  *****************\n
dialout:x:20:
tty:x:5:
************** modprobe *****************\n
Aug 29 23:08:44 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16985.437382] visor 2-2:1.0: device disconnected
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16995.992056] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156125] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0830, idProduct=0061
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156136] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156143] usb 2-2: Product: Palm Handheld
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156149] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Palm, Inc.
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156155] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: PalmSN12345678
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160134] visor 2-2:1.0: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter detected
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160433] usb 2-2: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160674] usb 2-2: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter now attached to ttyUSB1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 2 Aug 29 22:47 /dev/ttyUSB2
************** proc devices *****************\n
180 usb
188 ttyUSB
189 usb_device
************** mknob 0 *****************\n
************** mknob 1 *****************\n
************** mknob 3 *****************\n
************** chmod and chown  *****************\n
************** /dev/ttyUSB*  *****************\n
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Aug 29 23:09 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 1 Aug 29 23:09 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 2 Aug 29 22:47 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 3 Aug 29 23:09 /dev/ttyUSB3
************** pilot.rules *****************\n
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 141 Aug 29 20:46 /etc/udev/rules.d/palmtreo.rules
BUS=="usb", SYSFS{product}=="Palm Handheld*|Handspring *", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", NAME="ttyUSB%n", SYMLINK="pilot", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666"
************** pilot-dlpsh 0 *****************\n
   Unable to determine port to bind
   Please use --help for more information

************** pilot-dlpsh 1 *****************\n
   Unable to determine port to bind
   Please use --help for more information

************** pilot-dlpsh 2 *****************\n
   Unable to determine port to bind
   Please use --help for more information
************** pilot-dlpsh 3 *****************\n
   Unable to determine port to bind
   Please use --help for more information
************** pilot-xfer 0 *****************\n
   Listening for incoming connection on /dev/ttyUSB0... 
************** pilot-xfer 1  *****************\n
   Listening for incoming connection on /dev/ttyUSB1... 
************** pilot-xfer 2  *****************\n
   Unable to bind to port: /dev/ttyUSB2
   Please use --help for more information
************** pilot-xfer 3  *****************\n
   Unable to bind to port: /dev/ttyUSB3
   Please use --help for more information

************** /dev/ttyUSB*  *****************\n
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Aug 29 23:09 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 1 Aug 29 23:09 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 2 Aug 29 22:47 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 3 Aug 29 23:09 /dev/ttyUSB3

************** /dev/bus/usb/*  *****************\n

/dev/bus/usb/001:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     60 Aug 29 18:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    140 Aug 29 18:25 ..
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 0 Aug 29 18:25 001

/dev/bus/usb/002:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root          80 Aug 29 23:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root         140 Aug 29 18:25 ..
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root    189, 128 Aug 29 18:25 001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root dialout 189, 132 Aug 29 23:08 005

/dev/bus/usb/003:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       80 Aug 29 22:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root      140 Aug 29 18:25 ..
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 256 Aug 29 18:25 001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 339 Aug 29 22:43 084

/dev/bus/usb/004:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       60 Aug 29 18:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root      140 Aug 29 18:25 ..
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 384 Aug 29 18:25 001

/dev/bus/usb/005:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       60 Aug 29 18:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root      140 Aug 29 18:25 ..
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 512 Aug 29 18:25 001

************** /sys/dev/char/18*  *****************\n
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 22:44 /sys/dev/char/180:0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/usbmisc/hiddev0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 23:09 /sys/dev/char/188:0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 23:09 /sys/dev/char/188:1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 18:59 /sys/dev/char/189:0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 18:59 /sys/dev/char/189:128 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 23:09 /sys/dev/char/189:132 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 18:59 /sys/dev/char/189:256 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 22:44 /sys/dev/char/189:339 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 18:59 /sys/dev/char/189:384 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 18:59 /sys/dev/char/189:512 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5

************** /dev/usb/*  *****************\n
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     60 Aug 29 22:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root   4300 Aug 29 23:09 ..
crw-------  1 root root 180, 0 Aug 29 22:43 hiddev0
Aug 29 23:08:44 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16985.437382] visor 2-2:1.0: device disconnected
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16995.992056] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156125] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0830, idProduct=0061
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156136] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156143] usb 2-2: Product: Palm Handheld
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156149] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Palm, Inc.
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156155] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: PalmSN12345678
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160134] visor 2-2:1.0: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter detected
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160433] usb 2-2: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160674] usb 2-2: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter now attached to ttyUSB1
warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'?
See http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/blobs/master/Documentation/FAQ
root       785  0.0  0.1   8340  3544 ?        Ss   18:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -F
root       875  0.0  0.1   6700  2160 ?        Ss   18:26   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
root       917  0.0  0.1   8628  2748 ?        Ss   18:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
whoopsie  1117  0.0  0.2  61792  4572 ?        Ssl  18:26   0:00 whoopsie
1000      2113  0.0  0.2  47324  4416 ?        Sl   18:26   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-application-service
1000      2320  0.0  0.7 709228 16136 ?        Sl   18:27   0:01 nm-applet
1000      2497  0.0  1.6 424456 33920 ?        Sl   18:27   0:08 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/indicator-applet-complete
root     10712  0.0  0.0   2652   636 pts/3    S+   23:09   0:00 pilot-xfer -l --port=/dev/ttyUSB0
root     10713  0.0  0.0   2652   636 pts/3    S+   23:09   0:00 pilot-xfer -l --port=/dev/ttyUSB1
root     10734  0.0  0.0   4452   780 pts/3    S+   23:09   0:00 grep [u|U|j|v|p][s|S|i|p][b|B|s|i|l]

************** lsusb  *****************\n
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0830:0061 Palm, Inc. Lifedrive / Treo 650/680 / Tunsten E2/T5/TX / Centro / Zire 21/31/72 / Z22

************** sylog  *****************\n
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16995.992056] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156125] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0830, idProduct=0061
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156136] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156143] usb 2-2: Product: Palm Handheld
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156149] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Palm, Inc.
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.156155] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: PalmSN12345678
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160134] visor 2-2:1.0: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter detected
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160433] usb 2-2: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 kernel: [16996.160674] usb 2-2: Handspring Visor / Palm OS converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-2"
Aug 29 23:08:54 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Aug 29 23:08:59 Toshiba-Satellite-P105 whoopsie[1117]: online

************** ftdi_sio  *****************\n
filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    USB FTDI Serial Converters Driver
author:         Greg Kroah-Hartman <greg@kroah.com>, Bill Ryder <bryder@sgi.com>, Kuba Ober <kuba@mareimbrium.org>, Andreas Mohr, Johan Hovold <jhovold@gmail.com>
srcversion:     3EC1B476AE6B01A3C7D57BF
alias:          usb:v05D1p8004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        usbserial
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.11.0-26-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           vendor:User specified vendor ID (default=0x0403) (ushort)
parm:           product:User specified product ID (ushort)
parm:           ndi_latency_timer:NDI device latency timer override (int)




warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'?
See http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/blobs/master/Documentation/FAQ
root     10712  0.0  0.0   2652   636 pts/3    S+   23:09   0:00 pilot-xfer -l --port=/dev/ttyUSB0
root     10713  0.0  0.0   2652   636 pts/3    S+   23:09   0:00 pilot-xfer -l --port=/dev/ttyUSB1
root     10746  0.0  0.0   4448   792 pts/3    S+   23:09   0:00 grep pilot
warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'?
See http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/blobs/master/Documentation/FAQ
root     10748  0.0  0.0   4448   792 pts/3    S+   23:09   0:00 grep usb
warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'?
See http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/blobs/master/Documentation/FAQ
root       735  0.0  0.1   7884  2932 ?        Ss   18:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
root     10750  0.0  0.0   4452   796 pts/3    S+   23:09   0:00 grep mode
```

In JPilot when you click the hotsync it reports:

---

```
 Syncing on device /dev/ttyUSB0
 Press the HotSync button now
```

---

And hangs out indefinitely...

I click the hotsync button on the phone, and it times out eventually with the  error:
"The connection between your handheld computer and the desktop could not be established. Please check you setup and try again."

It's Palm v 2.5, JPilot 1.8.1.2

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

My best guess (total guess at this point) since I'm shaky on how the connection between Device 5: usb 2-2: (189, 132) @/dev/bus/usb/002 connects to /dev/ttyUSB0 or /dev/ttyUSB1. There doesn't seem to be any connection, and I'm unsure how to make it. I'm missing something, probably obvious to someone else who hasn't been starring at this most of the day. Any help getting me moving forward again is greatly appreciated!

```
/dev/bus/usb/002: 
crw-rw-r-- 1 root dialout 189, 132 Aug 29 23:08 005


lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 18:59 /sys/dev/char/189:256 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 22:44 /sys/dev/char/189:339 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2


************** pilot-xfer 0 *****************\n
   Listening for incoming connection on /dev/ttyUSB0... 
************** pilot-xfer 1  *****************\n
   Listening for incoming connection on /dev/ttyUSB1...
```

oh, and I did upgrade the MTP files (usb-modeswitch, usb-modeswitch-data) and verified that ftdi_sio is current, just in case it was causing the problem.

Comment: Some of the documents I've read to get me this far:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PalmDeviceSetup#Add%20the%20visor%20module%20to%20the%20kernel

http://lists.pilot-link.org/pipermail/pilot-link-general/2004-August.txt
http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-2

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a treo, but I've been syncing my palm regularly on LTS releases for the last 5+ years.

I have to tell you though, sync stopped working over the last week, and I've been pulling my hair out as to why.  But I just did another update, and sync is working again suddenly. I don't know if it's part of your problem, but force an update today if you can.

Here are my checks and steps to sync. Maybe something here will help.

- Ask root to add you to the `dialout` group. Then you need to logout and log in again. As a normal user, type this command to see what groups you belong to:

  groups
- Make sure `visor` is loaded. You can check as non-root by typing this in the terminal:

  ```
  modprobe visor 2>/dev/null ; echo $?  # you want to see a "0"
  ```
- Check to see if pilot-link package is present. as non-root do:

  ```
  test -e /usr/bin/pilot-xfer ; echo $?  # again, you want to see a "0"
  ```
- Attach the device via USB. I usually plug it in, unplug it, then plug it right back in a second time and conform a beep (Zire 72). The next command has to happen within 80 seconds:

  ```
  pilot-xfer --port usb: --list #connect and list databases, mostly harmless
  ```

Here you are using pilot-link (which jpilot uses too) to list your databases. You will need to hit the hotsync button on your device too.

If all of that worked, then the issue probably is going to be jpilot configuration.